# Arduino switch state display on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, arduino

I have successfully tested a web server using Ajax. The code below shows Arduino analog readings in a bar graph in the web page. Next I want to show a switch state like switch 1 / switch 2 (connected to pins 7 and 8) on /off in the web page.

Arduino code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
//Make sure to modify the 5100.h file to suit the Ethernet chip on your shield (eg. W5500) as per the gitHub instructions: https://github.com/Wiznet/WIZ_Ethernet_Library

byte mac[] = {
  0x00, 0x08, 0xDC, 0x1C, 0xB8, 0x4C
};
//Enter the MAC address that is on your Ethernet shield (sticker) - eg. 00-08-DC-1C-B8-4C (but use hexadecimal format eg. 0x00)

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 4);
//The IP address that you will give the Server - will depend on your local network range
EthernetServer server(8081);
//The port to listen for Web Browsers - the default is 80, but some routers will block this port.. so change to 8081.

//*************************************************************************************************
// setup function
//=================================================================================================
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Begin Serial communication (baud rate = 9600).
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  //Initialise the ethernet library and network settings: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin
  server.begin();
  //Tell the server to begin listening for incoming connections (on port 8081 in this example)
  Serial.print("Server IP address : ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  //If you see the IP address within the Serial monitor - you know that the server started successfully
}

//*************************************************************************************************
// loop function
//=================================================================================================
void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  // assign any newly connected Web Browsers to the "client" variable.
  if(client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Client Connected");
    while(client.available()) {
      //Serial.write(client.read());
      // Uncomment if you want to write the request from the Browser (CLIENT) to the SERIAL MONITOR (and comment out the next line)
      client.read();
      // This line will clear the communication buffer between the client and the server.
    }
    //Send the Server response header back to the browser.
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    // This tells the browser that the request to provide data was accepted
    client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    //Tells the browser it has accepted its request for data from a different domain (origin).
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
    //Lets the browser know that the data will be in a JSON format
    client.println("Server: Arduino");
    // The data is coming from an Arduino Web Server (this line can be omitted)
    client.println("Connection: close");
    // Will close the connection at the end of data transmission.
    client.println();
    // You need to include this blank line - it tells the browser that it has reached the end of the Server reponse header.
    //Transmit the Analog Readings to the Web Browser in JSON format
    //Example Transmission: [{"key":0, "value":300},{"key":1, "value":320},{"key":2, "value":143},{"key":3, "value":24},{"key":4, "value":760},{"key":5, "value":470}]
    client.print("[");
    // This is tha starting bracket of the JSON data
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
      // Transmit analog readings from Analog Pin 0 to Analog Pin 5
      client.print("{\"key\": ");
      client.print(i);
      // The key for Analog pin 0 (A0) is equal to 0   eg.  "key":0
      client.print(", \"value\": ");
      client.print(analogRead(i));
      // The value is equal to the Analog reading from that pin.  eg. "value":300
      if(i==5){
        client.print("}");
        // The last value will end with a bracket (without a comma)
      } else {
        client.print("},");
        // All other values will have a comma after the bracket.
      }
    }
    client.println("]");
    // This is the final bracket of the JSON data
    client.stop();
    // This method terminates the connection to the client
    Serial.println("Client has closed");
    // Print the message to the Serial monitor to indicate that the client connection has closed.
  }
}
```

Web page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>ArduinoBasics WebServer Data Viewer</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .table{
        width: 100%;
        background: #eeeeee;
        line-height: 32px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      .bars {
        float: left;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background: #FFFF33;
        color: #000000;
      }
      .row{
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
      }
    </style>
    <div align="center" style="background: #eeeeee; border: 1px solid black;">
      <h1>ArduinoBasics Data Viewer</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="IP Address" style="width: 220px; float:left" align="center">IP Address</div><div id="Port Num" style="width: 200px; float:left;" align="center">Port</div><br>
    <select id="Addr0"></select> .
    <select id="Addr1"></select> .
    <select id="Addr2"></select> .
    <select id="Addr3"></select> :
    <input id="port" value='8081' /><br>
    <button type="button" id="startData" style="height: 50px; width: 228px">Click here to start getting data</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button type="button" id="stopData" style="height: 50px; width: 172px">Click here to stop </button><br>&nbsp;
    <br>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row"><div class="bars">A0: </div><div class="bars" id="Analog0"></div><div class="bars" id="A0">0</div></div><br>
      <div class="row"><div class="bars">A1: </div><div class="bars" id="Analog1"></div><div class="bars" id="A1">0</div></div><br>
      <div class="row"><div class="bars">A2: </div><div class="bars" id="Analog2"></div><div class="bars" id="A2">0</div></div><br>
      <div class="row"><div class="bars">A3: </div><div class="bars" id="Analog3"></div><div class="bars" id="A3">0</div></div><br>
      <div class="row"><div class="bars">A4: </div><div class="bars" id="Analog4"></div><div class="bars" id="A4">0</div></div><br>
      <div class="row"><div class="bars">A5: </div><div class="bars" id="Analog5"></div><div class="bars" id="A5">0</div></div><br>
    </div>
    <br> &nbsp;
    <div id="FailureStatus"><H2>Status:</H2></div>
    <br> &nbsp;
    <div id="statusDiv"><i>This viewer is <b>not compatible</b> with Internet Explorer, and requires JavaScript.</i></div>
    <script>
      <!--This is the jQuery script which will connect to the Arduino -->
      var timeOut; //This variable is responsible for the frequency of data acquisition
      $(document).ready(function() {
        //Populate the options for the IP address drop-down boxes.
        for(j=0; j<256; j++) {
          for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
            $('#Addr'+i)
              .append($("<option></option>")
              .attr("value",j)
              .text(j));
          }
        }
        //Set the default IP address in the drop down boxes.
        $('#Addr0').val('10');
        $('#Addr1').val('1');
        $('#Addr2').val('1');
        $('#Addr3').val('99');
      });
      //When the start button is clicked - get the data from the Arduino
      $("#startData").click(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          getMyData(); //get data once the document is ready
        });
      });
      //Stop collecting data when the stop button is clicked.
      $("#stopData").click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        //This clears any future requests for data (until the Start button is pressed again)
      });
      function getMyData() {
        //get the IP address from the drop-down boxes
        var x0 = $('#Addr0 option:selected').text();
        var x1 = $('#Addr1 option:selected').text();
        var x2 = $('#Addr2 option:selected').text();
        var x3 = $('#Addr3 option:selected').text();
        //get the port number from the text box
        var x4 = $('#port').val();
        //Construct the URL of the Arduino Server we plan to connect to
        var myUrl = 'http://' + x0 + "." + x1 + "." + x2 + "." + x3 + ":" + x4 + "/";
        var myData = $.ajax({
          url: myUrl, // eg. http://10.1.1.99:8081/
          data: { tag: 'GetDataFromArduino'},
          dataType : "json", //We will be requesting data in JSON format
          timeout : 10000, //this will cancel the request if it has not received a reply within 10 seconds.
          success: function(data) {
            console.log('Success - you are a legend');
            $("#FailureStatus").html("<H2>Status: OK</H2>"); //clear any failure messages.
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
              if(element.value<100) {
                console.log('Low');
                $('#Analog' + element.key).css({'background-color':'#FF1128'});
              } else {
                $('#Analog' + element.key).css({'background-color':'#22FF22'});
              }
              $('#A'+element.key).html("<span>" + element.value + "</span>");
              $('#Analog' + element.key).animate({width: ((element.value/1023)*80)+"%"});
            });
          }
        });
        myData.error(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
          $("#FailureStatus").html("<span><H2>Status:FAILED to get DATA !! </H2></SPAN>");
          console.log('Failure');
          console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
          console.log("Status: " + status);
          console.dir(xhr);
        });
        timeOut = setTimeout('getMyData()', 1000); //this will request data again in 1 second.
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```